# DestroyCursor doesn't free GDI handle created by LoadCursor

Tags: winapi

(Windows) I'm creating cursors using LoadCursor, and deleting them using DestroyCursor.
However, using GetGuiResources it looks like the cursors GDI handles aren't being freed (the count remains the same after destroy). Why?

With GetGuiResources I can also see that LoadCursor obtains 2 GDI handles, not one. Why?

Comment: You can't call `DestroyCursor` on a cursor created by `LoadCursor` ([see MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms648386%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Comment: Thanks, how can I delete a shared cursor then?
And why didn't DestroyCursor return an error?

Comment: A shared cursor will be disposed of when the application exits, you don't need to do it yourself. You could call `LoadImage` instead and don't specify `LR_SHARED`, then you will create a non-shared cursor, which you *can* (and should) destroy. [See MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms648045%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Shouldn't I have received an error in attempting to destroy the shared cursor? And why did the count grow by 2 after LoadCursor?

Comment: If you received a non-zero return from `DestroyCursor`, you'd need to check with MS why that was. I imagine that the count grows by 2 because it keeps a handle open internally and passes a copy to each call of `LoadCursor`, but I'm just theorising here. You could call `LoadCursor` multiple times and see how the handle count behaves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm creating cursors using `LoadCursor`, and deleting them using `DestroyCursor`.

From the documentation of `DestroyCursor`:

> The DestroyCursor function destroys a nonshared cursor. Do not use
>   this function to destroy a shared cursor. A shared cursor is valid as
>   long as the module from which it was loaded remains in memory. The
>   following functions obtain a shared cursor:
>
> - LoadCursor
> - LoadCursorFromFile
> - LoadImage (if you use the LR_SHARED flag)
> - CopyImage (if you use the LR_COPYRETURNORG flag and the hImage parameter is a shared cursor)

The cursor returned by the call to `LoadCursor` is shared and you should not pass it to `DestroyCursor`. The shared cursor resources will be destroyed when the process terminates.

Comment: David, Do you have any insights on my other questions? Thanks.

Comment: You mean why the handle handle count grows by 2? No insights there. I don't really see why it matters though.